# 3 Table JOIN to show everything

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query from my 3 table, but i dont know which JOIN should I use. I want to display all of table2's item_id and item_name, also show stat and shipped from table3 even if its NULL. Also, user_id from table1.

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  shipped tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

I tired LEFT INNER JOIN, but I only got table3.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the query you tried, too, to make your question contain a [mre].

Comment: LEFT INNER JOIN - no such thing see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: The tables would be easier to understand and the queries in the answers easier to read, did you not name your tables table1, table2, and table3, but users, items and orders for instance. And yes, you should have shown your query. Then we could have told you what you got wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want all entries from tabl2 you should start there and add the other tables using `left outer join` or short `left join`

```
SELECT 
    t1.user_name,
    t2.item_name,
    t3.user_id,
    t3.item_id,
    t3.stat,
    t3.shipped
FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.item_id
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t3.user_id = t1.userid
```

Comment: Thank you! it works but the item_id says NULL if there is no data in t3. Is there a way to display that as well?

Comment: @master_of_nothingYou are welcome. If it is not existend? what would you show them?

Comment: i want to create a table like this: https://pastebin.com/XNCAEGtp
the user_id needs elswhere. i use it in php calls.

Comment: If you have no relation between table2 and table1, because of missing data in table3, how should it go?

Comment: Honestly, I dont know what relations should they have. T1 is filled with registered users and T2 is a list of items. T3 is where i store the user has this item (stat=1) or not (0). In the future there will be more item tables like T2 that i wanna link with the users.

Comment: @master_of_nothing But the relation between item and user does not exists if table3 is null, so you can not show it

Comment: @master_of_nothing: Maybe, just maybe, you are looking for a result for a particular user, and you want a list of all items along with the information whether the user ordered that item or not. And maybe you want something else entirely. The question you asked has been answered. If you want to ask a new question, then create a new request. There you can describe the task precisely, show sample table data and the related expected result and get your answer.

Comment: 'you are looking for a result for a particular user, and you want a list of all items along with the information whether the user ordered that item or not.' This is exactly what I want! Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can start from `table2` since this is the mandatory one and `LEFT JOIN` with the other two tables

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.user_name,
    t2.item_name,
    t3.user_id,
    t3.item_id,
    t3.stat,
    t3.shipped
FROM table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.item_id
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t3.user_id
```

Comment: You got the tables in the wrong order. You join t1 to t2, but the `ON` clause mentions t3, which is not yet joined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to achieve this. The LEFT JOIN will ensure that all records from table2 are included in the result, even if there are no matching records in table3

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t2.item_id, t2.item_name, t3.stat, t3.shipped
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.item_id
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t3.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query starts at `table2` as you need to show all items even if their status is null. Assuming that the relationship between `table2` and `table3` is a 1-1 then the below query will show you 1 line per item.

```
SELECT T2.ID
      ,T2.Item_Name
      ,T3.Stat
      ,T3.Shipped
      ,T3.ID
      ,T1.UserName
FROM table2 T2
LEFT JOIN table3 T3
ON T3.Item_ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN table1 T1
ON T1.ID = T3.UserID
```

Comment: The query looks fine, but it's highly unlikely that there is a 1:1 relation between table 2 and 3. Why should an item only be able to be shipped once?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner A 1:1 was assumed due to there not being a datetime present in the shipping table (just due to the tables I'm used to). I agree that it wouldn't just be a 1:1.